# Issues about quaternion and conversion

Tags: kinect, quaternion

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I an using the openni_tracker.cpp and the skeleton tracking. My questions are (A) how do I obtain the quaternion values of each join? (B) How do I convert each joint's rotation matrix (say 3 joints) to half space quaternion with respect to the torso in skeleton tracking. Thank you in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/96516/issues-about-quaternion-and-conversion/) by [SM](https://answers.ros.org/users/7146/sm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2013-10-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [openni_tracker](http://wiki.ros.org/openni_tracker) simply broadcasts transforms from the camera_frame_id frame (defaults to openni_depth_frame) to each of the joints of the user.  Using a [tf listener](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf%20listener%20(C%2B%2B)) one could write a simple node that looked up transforms between any two frames you are interested in.  For example you could lookup the transform between the /torso and the /right_elbow.  Once you have a transform object, the tf package provides functionality for converting to Euler angles, quaternions, SO(3), etc. See [the geometry page](http://wiki.ros.org/geometry) and the [rotation methods page](http://wiki.ros.org/geometry/RotationMethods).  Then you could publish this info as whatever type of message you want.

Alternatively, you could write your own node that modified the source of openni_tracker that published a custom message in the form you want.  I believe this is the route taken by the [pi_tracker](http://wiki.ros.org/pi_tracker) package.  I have also worked with my own package that does this same thing.  See https://github.com/jakeware/skeletontracker_nu and https://github.com/jakeware/skeletonmsgs_nu

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2013-10-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0